# Python Random module function

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I want to use the random module for a code I currently trying to solve:

```
def choice_to_number(choice):
    """Convert choice to number."""
    # If choice is 'rock', give me 0
    # If choice is 'paper', give me 1
    # If choice is 'scissors', give me 2
    if choice == 'rock':
        return 0
    elif choice == 'paper':
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

def number_to_choice(number):
    """Convert number to choice."""
    # If number is 0, give me 'rock'
    # If number is 1, give me 'paper'
    # If number is 2, give me 'scissors'
    if number == 0:
        return 'rock'
    elif number == 1:
        return 'paper'
    else:
        return 'scissors'

def random_computer_choice():
    """Choose randomly for computer."""
```

Need to find the code for the random part in order to solve it

Complete code: http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_rc6Pm3n7uj_0.py

Comment: what `random_computer_choice` should do? It expects no arguments.

Comment: What don’t you get about the `random` module? A simple `random.randint(0,2)` will get the result you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP have rather strange task. But I think the OP meant something like this:

```
def random_computer_choice():
    """Choose randomly for computer."""
    return random.choice(['rock','paper','scissors'])
```